# IE doesn't accept changing title of the web page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to change original title of the web page with another title using jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var newTitle = "The New Title";
        $("title").text(newTitle);
    });
</script>
```

This snippet of code works pretty fine on Google Chrome and Firefox but doesn't work on IE8 (which I've tested on), So what's wrong?!

And another related question: if I used this way to change title of the web page, then which title of them (original or new) google and other search engines will use in their indexing process?

Comment: Ok, thank you. But what about the second part of the question?

Comment: Google will use your original title for SEO/keywords etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jquery, plain javascript will work in your case,

```
 document.title = "The New Title";
```